# HTML content freezes when keyboard is shown using cordova for iOS

Tags: html, ios, cordova, keyboard

I have a cordova app where there is some input fields which requires the keyboard. But when the keyboard is open it's like the app is frozen. More specific, I have a div as a bottom bar which has a fixed position, but when the keyboard is opened, it can scroll, however when I close the keyboard, everything returns to the expected position. Any idea how to make it not freeze? This is only a problem on iOS. Android works perfect.

Comment: are you using jquery mobile?

Comment: no. everything is css. I am using jquery to edit the css sometimes but normally, it's just css

Answer (score 0):

My app has the same issue, selecting an input field causes the keyboard to show up and severely lag the app until the keyboard is hidden. After testing simple pages with no scripts or css on multiple devices I found that it primarily affects iPads on at least iOS 8.0 and above. It can cause slowdowns on iPhones but they seem to recover a lot faster.

The best solution I've found so far is to setup an in app keyboard. For my login page, I have an element that is styled as an input field and when it is clicked, it toggles a keyboard div element to appear which has buttons for each key inside it.